# Assigning a variable to a variable in Github action variables

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I'm new to yaml & Github & actions and trying to figure out how to assign x=y vs. x=value.  Is this possible?  In the example below, I'm trying to assign CertificatePath as a global variable to a concatenation of several directories.

```
    env:
      Solution_Name: WpfApp3.sln 
      Test_Project_Path: TestProject1\TestProject1.csproj
      Wap_Project_Directory: WapProjTemplate1
      Wap_Project_Path: WapProjTemplate1\WapProjTemplate1.wapproj
      SigningCertificate: GitHubActionsDemo.pfx
    - name: SetCertPath
      run: 
        $currentDirectory = Get-Location
        tempcertificatePath= Join-Path -Path $currentDirectory -ChildPath $env:Wap_Project_Directory -AdditionalChildPath $env:SigningCertificate
        echo "CertificatePath=${{ tempcertificatePath }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run multiple lines as part of a `run` step, you need to use a `|`. Furthermore, when assigning a variable, you don't need to use the `$` on the left hand side.

Example:

```yaml
- run: |
    myVar="foo"
    mySecondVar="${myVar}bar"
    echo $mySecondVar
```